# "unknown variant `base58`, expected `binary`" error when running `solana program show --buffers | --programs

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, error

When I run `solana program show --programs` ( or with --buffers ), I'm getting this weird error with no details on what's actually wrong. Any suggestions?

```
Error: RPC response error -32602: unknown variant `base58`, expected `binary` at line 1 column 140
```

Comment: What version of the CLI are you using? You may be using an old version with variants that are no longer supported, or this is a bug